# Is it Lashon Harah to tell someone's wife that you found her husband's wallet, since this might cause her to get upset with him for being careless?

Tags: halacha, lashon-hara-slander, shalom-bayit

Is it *Lashon Harah* to tell someone's wife that you found her husband's wallet, (if the husband did not publicize the loss, and you can tell the husband himself), since this might cause her to get upset with him for being careless?

(Does it depend on how likely it is that she will get upset with him? – Does it depend on whether she will / might express her disapointment to her husband?)

Comment: I don't see any mention of a situation where it's lashon hara based on someone else's **possible** intent to harm a person's reputation. Perhaps, it may be an issue of infringing on someone else's *Shalom Bayit*, which is a very different area. Practically, though, if you gave someone's wife a wallet, how would you explain why you're doing it? Would you just say, "Here's a wallet with some cash and credit cards in it. Have a nice day?"

Comment: @DanF 1- There is a halacha that it is forbidden to praise someone publically out of concern that people **possibly** may respond with negative comments. 2- Give it to the person directly, not to the wife. (or maybe just say to the wife, "Please give this to your husband" - (circumstantial).

Comment: #1 is the opposite of what you are proposing. #2 could (and probably would) still cause the problem, unless you give it to the person, directly.

Comment: @DanF 1- The opposite? How? 2- As I wrote it is circumstantial. I clearly asked would it be a LH problem if one DID have another option. (if no other option is available, and it is LH,  it may need all the conditions of LH L'toeles.)